# Word counter ignoring words after carriage return

Tags: javascript

I have this:

```js
var editor = document.getElementById('editor');
var words = document.querySelector('.words');

function wordsCount() {
 var arr = editor.textContent.trim().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').split(' ');
 words.textContent = !arr[0] ? 0 : arr.length;
}

editor.addEventListener('input', wordsCount);
wordsCount();
```

```css
body {
 width: max-content;
 font-family: 'Helvetica';
}
  
section {
 outline: 2px solid #BFDEFF;
}
  
aside {
 background-color: silver;
}
```

```html
<section id="editor" contenteditable="true">Default text</section>
<aside class="words"></aside>
```

The problem is that the script ignores words after a carriage return. So, if I type,

```
Example
Example
Example
```

it only counts one word instead of three. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead,

```
function wordsCount() {
    var arr = editor.innerText.trim().match(/\S+/g); //use innerText instead
    words.textContent = !arr[0] ? 0 : arr.length;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are no line breaks to begin with. Let's see what happens when you enter those three lines:

```
Example
Example
Example
```

The editor element's HTML now looks as follows:

```
<section id="editor" contenteditable="true">Example<div>Example</div><div>Example</div></section>
```

Instead of line breaks, new lines are wrapped by `<div>` elements.

Now, accessing `editor.textContent` returns the concatenation of the `textContent` property value of all child nodes. Thus, it returns `ExampleExampleExample`.

To fix your problem, you could replace `editor.textContent` with `editor.innerText` or simply use a `<textarea>` instead.

```js
const editor = document.getElementById('editor');
const output = document.getElementById('counter');

editor.addEventListener('input', event => {
  output.textContent = (editor.value.match(/\S+/g) || []).length;
});
```

```html
<textarea id='editor'></textarea>
<output id='counter'></output>
```

Comment: Can you please give me a live example of the `innerText` or `<textbox>`

Comment: `<textbox>` didn't work when I tried it. (Firefox 57.0.4 64-bit on Ubuntu.) But apart from that, I agree with this answer.

Comment: @DavidKnipe Interesting. I tested above textbox snippet with Firefox 58.0 64-bit on Ubuntu and it does count new lines. Did you run a different code snippet?

Comment: With `<html><head></head><body><textbox id="editor" contentEditable="true">Default text</textbox> </body></html>`, after typing `Default text` (with a newline) in the textbox, `document.getElementById('editor').textContent` returns `"Defaulttext"`.

Comment: @DavidKnipe The trick is to remove the contenteditable attribute from the textbox and use a textarea instead.